# Can anyone please explain about Maximum concurrent Analytics API calls per org limit as 100?

Tags: crm-analytics

I have build a CRM Analytics dashboard on experience site and I have 500 users who views the site, and in the CRM Analytics we have the limit stating "Maximum concurrent Analytics API calls per org limit as 100", what does this mean and can anyone explain it?

[image]

Comment: The limit is concurrent calls to API from all "sources" - your users, CRMA apps, any other automation or human traffic. It's unlikely that 500 users will hit this limit but to make sure of this, you should do a performance test. See Testing Strategy in https://architect.salesforce.com/well-architected/adaptable/resilient